# Authentication WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, asp.net-web-api

I just develop a mechanism for authentication for each WebAPI Action by using Attribute/Filter. i didn't use the "BuiltIn" Authorization functionality because i want to use my stored procedure and table structure.

I am asking the WebAPI user to provide the username and the password on every request as part of the request header. the username and the password transfers as Clear Text but the WebAPI configured to work only over HTTPS (SSL).

My security adviser told me that its not safe to transfer the username and the password as a clear text even over HTTPS (SSL) and asking me to encrypt the credential.

What is the simple way to do so? He suggested on Cookie but i am not sure WebAPI clients goes ok with Cookies since the WebAPI users are not only Browser clients some of the usages are Server to Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right approach, nor does it follow the [OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31) spec.

If you want to provide a header that is reauthenticated on every request, you should build an authorization server to generate a unique encrypted, timestamped token.  Pass that token on every request and authenticate against it, not the credentials.  That way you only expose the credentials once and there's far less likelihood of account compromise in the case that your token is successfully intercepted and decrypted.

If you need help using an OAuth library with an existing authentication server (google etc), look into http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: I got your point, thanks. Could you explain how the credentials will be encrypted at the first time?

Comment: Sure, depending on the provider, you submit your credentials and the authorization server returns the token for you.  If using something like Google for your authentication server, the user submits google credentials which you never see.  If you create your own backing authentication server, the user would submit their credentials to you and you would need to issue the encrypted token.  At no point however should you return an encrypted version of the credentials.  That defeats the entire point and creates a security loop hole.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using web api 2, you should look at owin based oauth authentication. The way it works is you will get oauth token after first time login, and you will have to send the oauth token on subsequent requests. For more information read the blogs from Dominick Baier - http://leastprivilege.com/category/oauth/.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please explain if by using owin, the username and the password will be encrypted at the client side and how?

Comment: You will have to do the encryption of token. The authorization server will return encrypted token, and on subsequent requests you will have to pass back the encrypted token.